# how to retrieve table from spss xml output in python

Tags: python, xml, spss

I trying to get some table outputs from `spssaux.CreateXMLOutput`. The spss command is validated from `spss.submit`. Below is a sample from my codes:

```
varList = ["QPOVTY", "PERCAP", "MDGRENT", "QRICH200K", "QNOAUTO", "QSSBEN", "QED12LES",
        "QFEMALE", "QAGEDEP", "QNATAM", "QHISP", "QASIAN", "QFEMLBR", "QSERV", "QEXTRCT", 
        "QCVLUN", "QFHH", "QFAM", "PRENTER", "QMOHO", "QUNOCCHU", "MHSEVAL"]
spssPCASyntax = ["FACTOR //VARIABLES " + ' '.join(varList) + " //MISSING LISTWISE" + 
               " //ANALYSIS " + ' '.join(varList) + 
               " //PRINT UNIVARIATE INITIAL CORRELATION KMO EXTRACTION ROTATION FSCORE" + 
               " //CRITERIA MINEIGEN(1) ITERATE(25)" + 
               " //EXTRACTION PC" + 
               " //CRITERIA ITERATE(25)" + 
               " //ROTATION VARIMAX" + 
               " // SAVE REG(ALL)" + 
               " //METHOD=CORRELATION."]
tag = spssaux.CreateXMLOutput(spssPCASyntax, omsid = 'Factor Analysis')
CorM = spssaux.getValuesFromXmlWorkspace(tag, 'Correlation Matrix')
print CorM
```

There is a error report about `CorM = spssaux.getValuesFromXmlWorkspace(tag, 'Correlation Matrix')` saying `[errLevel 12] Invalid handle object.`

I tried to debug this and dig into the spssaux module but cannot find a way to solve it. I check the call hierarchy and find one function is embedded inside some codes that cannot be viewed in DOS mode (codes appears only to be unrecognized symbols).

According to the code comments in `spssaux.getValuesFromXmlWorkspace`, it seems the minimum input of this function is `tag` and `tableSubtype`. The `tableSubtype` here is the String `Correlation Matrix` found as "OMS Table Subtype" in spss's output.

Can anyone help me with this or tell me how to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.  First, the return code from CreateXMLOutput is a duple of (tag, errorcode).  You should always check the error code.
tag, errcode = spssaux.CreateXMLOutput(...
The tag you would pass to getValuesFromXmlWorkspace would just be the first element.  In this case, the error code is 1001, and no output object is created, so the attempt to retrieve the output causes an error because the XPath expression evaluator can't find the object, and the tag item passed in is the duple, anyway, rather than the actual tag, so the argument is invalid.

So then the problem becomes why does the FACTOR command fail.  There are two problems.  One is that the syntax is invalid because all those // should just be /.  FACTOR might tolerate that, but it is incorrect.

Second, the assembled command probably exceeds the maximum line length.  I would just join the varList variables like
varList = "\n".join("xxx", "yyy:, etc
and then join the whole command into a single string with line breaks:
spssPCASyntax = "\n".join("FACTOR VARIABLES", ...)
and pass that string to CreateXMLOutput.

Tip: It is easier to assemble commands using named parameter substitution in a command string rather than joining the pieces with "+".  For example,
cmd = """commandname /varlist %(varList)s
    /someoption
    /someother options""" % locals()
This is more readable and less error prone.

Finally, here's a tip if you are trying to locate the line of code that raises an error.  By default, Statistics suppresses the traceback that the error would generate, because it would not be meaningful to most users.  However, if you create an environment variable named SPSS_EXTENSIONS_RAISE with value true before starting Statistics, the traceback is displayed, which allows you to pinpoint the error location in the code.

The way you create environment variables is OS specific, but on Windows you do this using Control Panel / System / Advanced / Environment Variables.  The exact wording and path varies in different Windows versions.

HTH
Jon Peck

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. In the source code of `spssaux.getValuesFromXmlWorkspace`, if the input tag is a tuple, it will automatically retrieve the first element as the real tag value. (I tried `tag, errcode = spssaux.CreateXMLOutput` and it makes no difference in my case.) Regards the FACTOR command, it runs fine if I use `spss.Submit` and python return correct results in the console. I will try putting line space into the command next Monday to see if it make differences. Maybe commands in `spss.Submit` and `spssaux.CreateXMLOutput` are evaluated in different way.

Comment: When I dig into the code, I suspect there is probably some inconsistency between XPath and the path generated by the input tag value. The SPSS version I used can pin point the error code and trace back to the root python code line, but i will try SPSS_EXTENSIONS_RAISE to see if it can further help me. Thank you for this tip ^ ^

Comment: I forgot that getValuesFromXmlWorkspace was so friendly about the tag, but your FACTOR syntax did not run for me.  I got an error code from createXmlOutput.  That function combines the syntax to run with some OMS commands.  If you are debugging you can see exactly what is being passed to spss.Submit.  That is creating a list of commands to pass to Submit, so  you shouldn't have another list in that list.  I supposed I could flatten the list containing lists, but it would be better to just create your commands as a multi-line string.

Comment: Oh, the sample code is not used for running and debug. I will update it tomorrow to a fully functional code for spss.submit.

Comment: Hi, Jon, I tried to change the SPSS command syntax by strictly following the syntax rule in SPSS and your tips. It works in `spssaux.CreateXMLOutput`! The problem actually happens when I submit the command syntax as list to `spssaux.CreateXMLOutput`. It should be a string format, because the command syntax from `spssaux.CreateXMLOutput` to `spss.Submit` will be embed into a new command list. So, when I input the command syntax as an 1 dimensional list, the command syntax to `spss.Submit` will be a 2 dimensional list, which cannot be accepted by the evaluation function in `spss.Submit`.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you should submit it as a string (with line breaks) not as a list by using the parameter substitution format to build your command.  If I get a chance, I'll add code to flatten the list, but for now just use the string form.  If you want to send me a small job and data (jkpeck at gmail.com) I'll show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to look at this on Saturday (I'm the author of this module), but I would like to know the version of Statistic, the OS, and the spssaux version.  I would also like to have a small sample of data that shows the problem.

Comment: he SPSS is the latest version (seems 22, I can go back and check it on next Monday). The OS is windows 7. the spssaux is installed with the latest spss version. I can check the specific version in next Monday. The input sample data is create by `with spss.DataStep():`. Inside this, I simply create a `spss.Dataset` and append variables to its variable list, and cases to this dataset. This dataset is validated in `spss.Submit` and the python console returns the right results. If you want to see the details of the inputs, i can share a link with you.

Comment: I checked the SPSS version. It's 23. The spssaux version is 2.6.0